# No reputation today?

Tags: support, reputation

I have just done a couple of edits (e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9211700)), which obviously have been accepted. Yet no change in reputation is displayed. Please don't get me wrong: Rep collection is not my main concern (*well, what did you expect me to say?*), but this looks as if something is broken, which has been working yesterday. Or am I for some unknown reason being blocked from reputation manna?

Comment: @Stijn's correct. In addition a lot of your edits are tag only edits - a lot of those posts could have done with other edits while you were at it...

Comment: You can check on your [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9211700), under **Editor stats** that you have 500+ edit suggestions approved, and as Stijn said: you'll never gain more rep suggesting edits ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation

> **You gain reputation when:**
>
> - suggested edit is accepted: +2 (up to +1000 total per user)

You've probably hit the 1000 reputation limit.

Comment: Ok, that's possible. Shame on me, did not have this limit in mind.

Comment: @f_puras you can do a complete audit of your reputation by visiting this link while logged in http://stackoverflow.com/reputation and at the bottom of the report, you will see how much reputation you've earned from suggestions.